# Access NSProgressIndicator outside of NSTableViewDelegate method

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, nsview

Within one of my tableview delegate's methods I programmatically create and add to the superview an NSProgressIndicator

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let mainview = NSTableCellView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 48))

    //PROGRESS INDICATOR
    let progAsset = NSProgressIndicator(frame: NSRect(x: 32, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width - 32, height: 20))
        progAsset.indeterminate = false
        progAsset.wantsLayer = true
        progAsset.layer!.hidden = false
        progAsset.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = true
        progAsset.identifier = "\(val)"

    mainview.addSubview(progAsset)
    progAsset.incrementBy(progRatio)

    return mainview
}
```

I have been searching for a while in an attempt to find the most efficient method of accessing `progAsset` in a completely different method but to no avail.

Any advice on how to access this object in a different method would be greatly appreciated.

PS. The tableView I use will be refreshed at many points during the applications runtime using the table's `reloadData()` method.

Comment: This doesn't look like objective-C.

Comment: @ScottHunter I can use an answer in objective-c

Comment: the classic approach is to assign an unique tag to the progress indicator, then get the NSTableCellView for the appropriate column and call `let progAsset = view.viewWithTag(123) as! NSProgressIndicator` while view is the NSTableCellView instance

Comment: @stklieme I wanted to use tags, however I could not find the right way to assign a tag to an NSProgressIndicator

Comment: @stklieme the 'tag' property for `NSProgressIndicator` is read-only

Comment: you could subclass NSProgressIndicator and redefine tag as r/w

Comment: or use this solution without tags `let subviews = view.subviews.filter { $0 is NSProgressIndicator }
if !subviews.isEmpty {
  let progAsset = subviews[0] as! NSProgressIndicator
}`

Comment: @stklieme I used your suggestion in another method `var progAsset = NSProgressIndicator()
                let subviews = view.subviews.filter { $0 is NSProgressIndicator }
                if !subviews.isEmpty { progAsset = subviews[0] as! NSProgressIndicator }
                progAsset.incrementBy(20)`   But it did not seem to work